# Read dataset.train and dataset.test in r

Tags: r, dataformat

I am doing a project about high dimension data set, the data set is from http://archive.ics.uci.edu/, it can also be found in github  (https://github.com/minghust/MaliciousExeDetect/tree/master/TrainData)

The file is called "dataset.train","tst.test". I want to read them in R. 
My question is whether there are file format, called .train, and .test file. They are not csv, or txt file. How i can open it and import it in R?

Comment: the url in Q is not directing to the dataset..care to revise the Q? Besides, the Q is unclear. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to ask

Comment: I don't understand how that data is structured as there is no header. How many rows and column are present?

Comment: Attribute information: Hybrid Features ( hexdump and DLL) from an executable. feature been stated in dataset along with 1 while rest are ignored and feature set ends with -1 ie say ( +1 2:1 5:1 45:1 .............. -1) so here +1 states a NON-malacious file while 2:1 states 2nd feature exists similarly for 5,45 while features which do not occur are simply ignored. Number of Attributes: 513